# When are HLSL literals taken as a float and integer?

Tags: shaders, hlsl

```
float2 uv = float2(fX % 1, fY % 1) * 1/16;
```

In the above example 1/16 is treated as a float, multiplying the float2 by 0.0625, but in:

```
float2 uv = float2(fX % 1, fY % 1) * 1/16 + float2(1/16,0);
```

The second 1/16 is taken as an integer and the second float2 becomes (0,0).

What's the order in which a specific type is used.  And is there any suffix to force a float?  I know 1.0/16.0 would work.

Comment: In C# the suffix F forces a float instead of either double (the default floating-point type) or any integer type.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I know, but this is isn't C#?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: this is for HLSL, not C#.  The rules are a bit different.  There is no `f` suffix in HLSL.  Anything with a decimal is a 32-bit single-precision float and then you can use the `L` suffix to make it a 64-bit double.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch: Yes, I read the tag - but since it is another Microsoft product there was a chance it was similar.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: fair enough, but I figured it was worth clarifying. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a decimal to mark a type as a float.  `1.0` is always floating point.  Hence `1.0/16` or `1/16.0` will always be floating point.

Numeric literals are treated as floats if used in a floating-point context.  Remember that operators like `*` and `/` are left-associative.  So in your first example, the code is equivalent to `(float(...) * 1) / 16`.  If you put the `1/16` in parentheses then it would be equal to `0` and that would be multiplied with the vector, e.g `float2(...) * (1/16) == float2(0,0)`

In your second example, the `1/16` is seen by itself, computed (as integers, because there's no float involved), and then the *result* of the expression is converted to float for the `float2` construction.  You need to cause either the `1` or the `16` to be a float in order for the `/` operator to be in a float context and force the other value to be treated as a float.

Comment: I voted to move the question to StackExchange but saw no answers to this question there.  Hopefully this answer can be moved with the question if the vote goes through.